# How to bevel a 90 degree angle; evenly distributed, and the faces at the ends remain straight(aligned to the original 90 degree)?

Tags: bevel

Here are the original edge lengths for reference:
[image]

I select the corner edge and bevel with four parts to make a total of six faces like I want, and they are evenly measured amongst themselves, but the outer edge faces are excluded. How can I include them but not have them become bent like the bevel faces?

Hopefully my description is clear, please ask if you need more clarification. Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]